# WPF application doesn't run on another computer

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a new WPF project. I copied the built .exe file onto another computer and tried to run the application. But nothing happened. It was just loading. Nothing more.

All my WPF projects do this thing.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone any idea?

**Edit**: For somebody in the future: the question might not be clear. What I meant was that I created a simple WPF application with nothing in it and tried to run the application on another computer. I wasn't able to make it run. Just nothing appeared. **I figured out that the Avast Free Antivirus was causing this problem.** When the antivirus is turned off, it runs as expected. Even though it is no solution, at least we know, what was causing the problem.

Comment: Does second machine has targeted .NET Framework installed?

Comment: To find issue on second machine see [Application Event Log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx)

Comment: @AdnanUmer .NET Framework is istalled on the other computer. When I look at this folder "Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\" there is the newest version of .NET framework (v4.0.30319).,

Comment: @AdnanUmer Application Event Log didn't help. It didn't show any issue.

The application doesn't run on any computer. Not only on that one computer.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the dot net libraries on the target machine.

For quick fix, download the dot net framework distributable for the .net version you compiled against and install it on the target machine. Here is [4.5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40779) for example.

For actual distribution, look at creating an installer that will ensure all dependencies are installed with the application. [InstallShield](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio) has a limited edition which may be included with your edition of visual studio

Comment: The application doesn't run on any computer, not just on that one. 

On that computer where I tried to run my application is installed Windows 10 and part of the Windows is .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing your application using click once. You can do this by right clicking on your project > Publish > Specify the location to publish your application > Finish. Copy the files inside the Published folder to another computer and try installing by click the setup.

Note: The instructions I said above only works if you only have basic functions on your app. If your application uses SQL Server, you need to install it first on the computer that you will be installing your application in.

For your reference. [How to: Publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)